# Split class declaration over multiple lines

Tags: php

I have a class that implements a lot of interfaces. How can I split the declaration over multiple lines? Something like:

```
class MyClass extends MyParent implements (
    MyInterfaceA,
    MyInterfaceB,
    MyInterfaceC,
    etc
)
```

Comment: Just add newlines to a normal `implements A, B, C, ...` anywhere you like…?

Comment: There is no need for brackets round the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses are invalid syntax, just get rid of them.

```php
class Cat extends Animal implements
    FelineInterface,
    SuperstitionInterface,
    NineLivesInterface
{
    private $lives = 9;
    private $color = 'tan';

    // From FelineInterface
    function sayMeow() {
        echo 'Meow!';
    }

    // From SuperstitionInterface
    function scaryAttributes() {
        echo ['color' => $this->afraidOf];
    }

    // Watch out for black cats.
    function afraidOf() {
        return $this->color === 'black';
    }

    // From NineLivesInterface
    function livesLeft() {
        echo $this->lives;
    }
}
```